# Is there a way to tell if two identically-named ZFS snapshots are actually identical?

Tags: zfs

How can you tell if two ZFS snapshots are identical or simply named the same?

Say I have two computers named `host-a` and `host-b`.  Also assume that `host-a` has a ZFS dataset named `/tank/mydataset`.

On host-a, I could: `zfs snapshot tank/mydataset@mysnapshot' and then I could 'zfs send tank/mydataset@mysnapshot | ssh host-b zfs receive tank/mydataset`

This would mean `@mysnapshot` would be identical on both `host-a` and `host-b`.

On the other hand, on `host-a` I could: `zfs snapshot tank/mydataset@mysnapshot` followed by `ssh host-b zfs snapshot tank/mydataset@mysnapshot`.

In this second case, the two snapshots are identically named, but the dataset may be wildly different.

Looking at the properties of `tank/mydataset@mysnapshot` doesn't list any apparent way of identifying if the snapshots are identical--i.e. a GUID or hash.

Other than trying to take another snapshot of `host-a` `tank/mydataset@mysnapshot2` and trying to send to `host-b` via `zfs send -i @mysnapshot tank/mydataset@mysnapshot2 | ssh host-b zfs receive tank/mydataset` is there a way of determining that the snapshots are identical not only in name, but blocks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a property *specifically* for this use-case.

`zfs get guid pool/fs@snap` will give you a GUID (Globally Unique ID) for a snapshot. If the GUID doesn't match between two snapshots, one isn't replicated from the other, and they won't work as a basis for further incremental replication.

This is also how [syncoid](https://sanoid.net/) identifies common snapshots to determine replication commands.

(Disclaimer: I am the initial developer and chief maintainer for the Sanoid project, which the Syncoid replication tool belongs to.)

Comment: Ooh...syncoid....you may have solved two of my problems with one answer. I'll have to check it out. Thanks!  :)

Comment: @Jim Salter The link your posted is now stale. You may want to update it to the github page. https://github.com/jimsalterjrs/sanoid/blob/master/syncoid